# Tensorflow-gpu is refusing to run with a strange error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I have just purchased an RX 2070, installed microsoft visual studio, then CUDA, then cuDNN. After this I installed anaconda and issues commands

pip install tensorflow-gpu

pip install keras

With in theory a functioning version of tensorflow-gpu I attempted to run my neural network which was working under the cpu version and the following error appeared.

The same error appears under any attempt to import tensorflow

> File "", line 1, in
>   runfile('C:/Users/g/Desktop/Masters-Project/Gaussian ROC
>   example/Neural Network Worked Example.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/g/Desktop/Masters-Project/Gaussian ROC example')
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'),
>   namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/g/Desktop/Masters-Project/Gaussian ROC example/Neural
>   Network Worked Example.py", line 7, in from keras.models import
>   Sequential as sequential
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py",
>   line 3, in from . import utils
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py",
>   line 6, in from . import conv_utils
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py",
>   line 9, in from .. import backend as K
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py",
>   line 89, in from .tensorflow_backend import *
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 5, in import tensorflow as tf
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 22, in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint:
>   disable=unused-import
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in raise ImportError(msg)
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper _mod =
>   imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname,
>   description) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in
>   load_module return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>   return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module
>   could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

I've been unable to resolve this, I can confirm to the best of my ability the other packages are correct and I'm absolutely stumped as to what's wrong.

Comment: Could you format the error as code instead of quote?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you install the correct Cuda and Cudnn versions. You can check the required versions in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), if the error still persists try  reinstalling tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) and type:

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

it will download all the dependencies including Cuda and Cudnn